# \changebarsep does not work when changebar stretches accoss pages

Tags: xetex, changebar

I use `\changebarsep` to adjust the separation between changebar and textbody. When the changebar stretches across pages, the separation set does not work as shown on the attached figures. Why? and how to deal with it?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[color]{changebar}

\begin{document}
\setlength\changebarsep{30pt}
%\setlength\changebarwidth{10pt}
\cbcolor{red}
This is some text.\\

\cbstart 
Here is some text that has to be marked with the usual changebar.
\cbend 

\vskip 45em
This is some further text.\\
%
\cbstart 
Here is some text that has to be marked with a different changebar.Here is some text that has to be marked with a different changebar.Here is some text that has to be marked with a different changebar.Here is some text that has to be marked with a different changebar.Here is some text that has to be marked with a different changebar.Here is some text that has to be marked with a different changebar.Here is some text that has to be marked with a different changebar.Here is some text that has to be marked with a different changebar.Here is some text that has to be marked with a different changebar.
\cbend

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: your first text has paragraph indentation, that's why the space is larger. Add a second line, to see the difference. And you should more the changebarsep setting into the preamble.

Comment: Thank you very much for your proposal! After putting the changebarsep setting into the preamble, I get the right separation. If a third changebar is needed in my case with a different changebarse(15pt for example), how to do that? I tried again `\setlength\changebarsep{15pt}` in the main body and failed with on supprising.